# How to change language in Azure Health Bot using Whatsapp as a channel?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, azure-bot-service, microsoft-health-bot

We are developing a Chat solution using Azure Health Bot
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/health-bot/

I'm using Whatspp (Twilio) as an access channel for end users.

What I want is to provide the users a language selection and based on their selection localization language would be set.

Azure Health Bot provide Localization feature But I can't find anywhere How to change the language programmatically (from designer/using script).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/health-bot/localization

If there is a way to change the locale in runtime based on user selection this would solve my problem

I tried to use local variables with the languages and sentences I have, But the problem is Azure Health Bot have pre-defined error messages that Will not get translated unless locale is changed using a proper method to the desired language.

Microsoft Azure Health Bot is exposing `conversation.locale` as a readonly variable to get the current used language. But there is no way to set this locale programmatically.